# Search List FirstOrDefault StartsWith fuzzy

Tags: c#, list, fuzzy-search, startswith

If I use the following code I will find an Item.ShowName starting with “X” – if one exists.

```
List<Artist> myList = new List<Artist>();
//Fill list with items
Artist Item = myList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("X"));
```

My problem is if there is no Item.ShowName starting with “X”. In that case I want the nearest match, i.e. the first Item starting with “Y” or the last Item with “W” in my list.
Obviously I can enumerate through the whole list but this might be slow. What is a fast way to get the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a little trick you can use to do so :

```
Artist Item = myList.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                    .OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x[0] - (int)'X')).FirstOrDefault();
```

Convert 'X' and first character of x to integer, order by the absolute value of the difference.

Comment: Thanks, I just implemented it and it works fine. I calculate the first letter code (using only lower case ASCII codes) when I add my items to my list. It works fast and correct.